# TypeError: Errpr #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, typeerror

I'm trying to load some pictures from my XML file (The pictures are URL:s from another site)

Wich I've managed to do (Atleast make them visible)

Now I'm trying to get all the elements in my tag  and show them in my textbox (errorMessage)

But somehow I can't even trace anything beyond my xmlLoadedImages function and I get this error.

> *TypeError: Errpr #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties AS3*

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import fl.containers.UILoader;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;


var xmlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Vehicles.xml");
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlRequest);
var imgData:XML;

var imageLoader:Loader;
var titleLoader:Loader;
var raw_image:String;
var raw_text:String;

var title:String;
var message:String;
var imgNum:Number = 0;      


xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedImages);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, wrong);


function wrong(evt:IOErrorEvent):void{
    errorMessage.text="Something's wrong.";
}


function xmlLoadedImages(event:Event):void
{

    var A:Array=[image1_mc,image2_mc,image3_mc,image4_mc];

    imgData =  new XML(event.target.data);

    var imageLength:int = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.children().length();
    //trace(imageLength);
    for (var i: int = 0; i < imageLength; i++)
    {
        raw_image = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.Url[i];
        imageLoader = new Loader;
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(raw_image), context);
        A[i].addChild(imageLoader);
        A[i].height = 150;
        A[i].width = 150;


    }
    message = imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList;
    trace(message);

}
function xmlLoadedText(event:Event):void
{
    var xmlLength:int = imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList.children().length();
    //trace(xmlLength);

    for(var b:int = 0; b < xmlLength; b++)
    {
        trace(imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList.Equipment[b])
        var B:Array = [imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList.Equipment[b]];
        trace(B);
        errorMessage.text = B.toString();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Here is some of my XML, mostly those parts I am using.

```
        <EquipmentList>
        <Equipment>ABSBrakes</Equipment>
        <Equipment>Airbags8</Equipment>
        <Equipment>Alarm</Equipment>
        <Equipment>Alloy16</Equipment>
        <Equipment>AutomaticClimateControl</Equipment>
        <Equipment>AutomaticGeartronic</Equipment>
        <Equipment>CruiseControl</Equipment>
        <Equipment>CupHolder</Equipment>
        <Equipment>ESP</Equipment>
        <Equipment>ExternalThermometer</Equipment>
        <Equipment>Immobilizer</Equipment>
        <Equipment>LeatherSteeringWheel</Equipment>
        <Equipment>LoweredSuspension</Equipment>
        <Equipment>Navigation</Equipment>
        <Equipment>NonSmoker</Equipment>
        <Equipment>OneOwner</Equipment>
        <Equipment>PoweredMirrorsHeated</Equipment>
        <Equipment>RemoteCentralLocking</Equipment>
        <Equipment>SeatHeater</Equipment>
        <Equipment>ServiceOK</Equipment>
        <Equipment>TaintedWindowsRear</Equipment>
        <Equipment>TripComputer</Equipment>
        <Equipment>WhiteTurningSignal</Equipment>
    </EquipmentList>
    <PictureCount>5</PictureCount>
    <Pictures>
        <Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700008.jpg</Url>
        <Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700008_1.jpg</Url>
        <Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700008_2.jpg</Url>
        <Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700008_3.jpg</Url>
        <Url>http://images.bilinfo.dk/images/44700008_4.jpg</Url>
    </Pictures>
```

Comment: Do you get a line number with your error? Could you post some of your xml?

Comment: So i've put up the parts of the XML i'm using. and no I don't get any line number :( That's why it's so hard to find out where the undefined property is

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that error happens in xmlLoadImages method?

Comment: It seems like it's there the problem is. I've tried outcommenting everything else and still end up with the same error. So i think it's safe to say that somewhere in the xmlLoadImages function there is a property is undefined

Comment: trace(imageLength) is not reached as well?

Comment: I can trace the ImageLength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I hade only four UILoaders (changed it to UILoaders) And the

```
 for (var i: int = 0; i < imageLength; i++)
```

tried to put in 5 elements (Had five elements in my XML) and that's where the last unidentified property went